# How to create two different value Vue-Router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

SOLUTİON:

This is router.js file---

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Hey from "./components/hey.vue"
import Search from "./components/search.vue"

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Home",
      component: Search
    },
    {
      path: "/:positionName/:jobId",
      name: "JobDetail",
      component: Hey
    }
  ] 
});
```

--

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      positionName: this.$route.params.positionName,
      id: this.$route.params.jobId,
      items: {}
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.$http
      .get(
        "http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cqdiacEgfC?indent=2" +
          this.positionName +
          this.id
      )
      .then(function(data) {
        this.items = data.body;
      });
  }
};
```

---

I want to create a router with two different value coming from json data.

http://localhost:8080/(positionName)/(jobId). this is what i mean.

We have two page. one of search.vue page, other one hey.vue. we search jobs by tag or key. if we find jobs then we must see job details. and when i click "go to details" then vue must show us job details.

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      positionName: this.$route.params.positionName,
      id: this.$route.params.jobIb
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.$http
      .get("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ceHCLxJcOa?indent=2" + this.positionName + this.jobIb)
      .then(function(data) {
        this.items = data.body.slice(0, 1);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
<div> 
    <div class="card-body" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id"> 
        <h5 class="card-title">{{item.positionName}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{item.companyName}}</p>
        <p class="card-text">{{item.description}}</p>
        <p class="card-text">{{item.countryName}}</p>
        <p class="card-text">{{item.cityName}}</p>
        <p class="card-text">{{item.address}}</p>
        <p class="card-text">0{{item.contactPhone.areaCode}}-{{item.contactPhone.number}}</p>
        <input type="button" value="Başvur!" class="btn btn-danger">

    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

How can i do or What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You main question is unclear. Do you struggle creating a route with 2 dynamic params coming from a server?

Comment: You didn't show your router, are you using nested routes? https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Comment: yes i want to create a route 2 dynamic params. and i add router.js.

Comment: Omer, I think I know exactly what you are talking about, I did it a few months ago in my router.js. If the answer below helps, please don't forget to accept the answer. Thank you very much. If not, let me know and I'm happy to work with you to get a working solution.

Comment: i found the solution i think. it's work for me. edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing your router code.

Here is an example of mine:

```
{
  path: '/search/:term/:page',
  name: 'SearchPage',
  secure: true,
  component: SearchPage,
},
```

So in your case it may be something like:

```
{
  path: '/job/:positionName/:jobID',
  name: 'JobPage',
  component: JobPage,
},
```

So you can see that I have two named parameters prepended with a colon (:).

Once I am on `/search/{term}/{page}` I can access those Parameters within the page with what you have in the Data() return.

```
data() {
  return {
    positionName: this.$route.params.positionName,
    id: this.$route.params.jobID
  };
},
```

Comment: Just for the fun of it, there is another way you could do it. You could also just pass one of the values in via a query, like `/job/:positionName?jobID=xx` and access it with `this.$route.query.jobID`.